# MYSQL commands and Encoding

Tags: mysql, encoding

I will use PhP notation for variables to make life easy.

Suppose the database is UTF-8, and the client is set to UTF-8.

There are two sides to the question. Knowing that the ASCII for ' (quote) is 39 decimal:

**Client Side**
    When the query variable, $title, is escaped, using function such as *real_escape_string()*, will the function escape all bytes that have value of 39 separately? Or will it see if the byte of value 39 is a part of UTF-8 symbol?

**Server Side**

```
SELECT * from STORIES WHERE title = 'Hello'
```

What does MYSQL assume the query encoding to be? This includes the part:

```
SELECT * from STORIES WHERE title = '
```

Then if a $filteredTitle happens to have the byte 39 in it which is part of a UTF-8 symbol, how does MYSQL know that it is not a quote?

Comment: IMHO too much worry about nothing. did you really try to: `"SELECT * from STORIES WHERE title = '".mysql_real_escape_string($title)."'"` ?

Comment: I am trying to understand how it work. What is wrong with the query you mentioned?

Comment: if you are trying to understand mysql is open source you can read all sources. Why it must be something wrong with query string I suggested?

Comment: You asked: "Did you really try to". The word "really" made me think that you are implying something is wrong with the query :-). To the source code I shall marsh.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at two issues.

1. When providing a `SELECT` statement, strings must be "escaped".  Otherwise, there would be syntax problems with quotes inside quotes.  In particular `'`, `"`, and `\` must be preceded by a backslash to avoid confusion.  `mysqli_real_escape_string()` provides that function.  (Don't use `mysql_real_escape_string()`, it belongs to the deprecated `mysql_*` API.)  No "un-escaping" is needed when you `SELECT` the string.
2. The ascii apostrophe (decimal 39, hex 27, sometimes called "single quote") is commonly used in many programming languages for quoting strings.  A long list of utf8 "quotes" can be found [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#quotes).

Comment: So is the command: "SELECT * FROM sometable" always pure ASCII, but the command "SELECT somecolumn FROM sometable where somecolumn = 'someEncodedString'"; will treat only the 'someEncodedString' as encoded?

Comment: When you use PHP or other languages, you need to say something like `$sql = "SELECT ... WHERE c = 'string'";`  If "string" has any quotes in it, they must be escaped, else PHP (etc) would complain.  The escaping gets past the strings-within-strings syntax issue.